# Replicated MySQL write performance query

Tags: mysql, galera

Whilst I've worked with MySQL for years, I've never had to created a replicated database, and after researching the topic I have a query about performance.

I'm thinking of an architecture based on 5 servers, one of them designated as the master and will handle ALL write transactions, whilst the other 4 will handle read requests.

My question is, if the master server is at 90% CPU usage handling writes, are the other servers in the cluster also under the same strain due to each write being sent to all other servers? or is something going on where the bulk of the processing is handles on the master so the slaves do less work processing the write transaction?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the query and the binary log format.

An UPDATE query that fetches lots of rows and changes very few will in `binlog_format=ROW` end up as `UPDATE table SET x=y WHERE PK=z` so will have a lower CPU/IO overhead. If it was using `binlog_format=STATEMENT` exactly the same query would end up on the slave.

Conversely a UPDATE query that updates a large number of rows, `UPDATE table SET status=Fixed WHERE date < NOW()` will generate a large number on binary log entries (for each primary key) and might be slower in `binlog_format=ROW` than statement.

There's a good document on this in the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html)

Based on your galera tag, and the [known limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations), you'll be using `binlog_format=ROW` and each table will have a primary key. Take note regarding transaction size so to avoid stalls due to large updates.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  While danblack is stating valid stuff, there is another dimension to the Question.

Yes, all the writes on the Master must be repeated on each Slave.  But not necessarily in the same format.

Suppose you have a long complicated transaction that does some complex selects, but only inserts one row in a table.  What gets replicated is the insert.  The rest bogged down the Master, but was not repeated on the Slaves.  (Yeah, there are variants where the opposite is true.)

If, on the other hand, everything going on on the Master is simple inserts/updates deletes *with* good indexes, then the load on the Slaves could be high.

Row-Based-Replication sends only the effect of the operation, so not even the complexity of the index lookup (or lack of it) is repeated on the Slave.  So *usually* RBR is less burden on the Slaves than SBR.

Depending on your version, you may be able to take advantage of multiple threads applying the changes on the Slave.  (Actually, this impacts how fast a Slave can slog through the changes more than whether the CPU is pegged.)